Dmesg showing incidents in the future
While debugging Wifi issues I came across this anomaly:
$ sudo dmesg -e

[Jul 1 14:28] wlxd85d4c93a47f: deauthenticating from 1c:57:3e:96:c3:a3 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  +1.457910] wlxd85d4c93a47f: authenticate with 1c:57:3e:96:c3:a3
[  +0.123528] wlxd85d4c93a47f: send auth to 1c:57:3e:96:c3:a3 (try 1/3)
[  +0.001831] wlxd85d4c93a47f: authenticated
[  +0.002090] wlxd85d4c93a47f: associate with 1c:57:3e:96:c3:a3 (try 1/3)
[  +0.004359] wlxd85d4c93a47f: RX AssocResp from 1c:57:3e:96:c3:a3 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=18)
[  +0.005915] wlxd85d4c93a47f: associated
[  +0.072269] wlxd85d4c93a47f: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 1c:57:3e:96:c3:a3
[  +0.017627] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxd85d4c93a47f: link becomes ready

$ date
2024-07-01T14:25:54 IDT

Why might dmesg show the time of an event as Jul 1 14:28 when the current time is 14:25? This is on Kubuntu 22.04.
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l

$ uname -a
Linux nefora 5.15.0-105-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 09:52:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


From the man page of dmesg:

   -T, --ctime
      Print human-readable timestamps.
      Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate! The time
      source used for the logs is not updated after system
      SUSPEND/RESUME. Timestamps are adjusted according to current
      delta between boottime and monotonic clocks, this works only
      for messages printed after last resume.


In my experience, the dmesg timestamps can vary quite a bit from the system clock.
If you're using systemd-journald you can get the corresponding system time with journalctl --facility kern.

Thank you. It should be noted that this is a desktop machine, and has never been suspended nor resumed.

There are a few other things to consider as well. The dmesg timestamp uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC, which is basically seconds since boot (apparently that's not 100% POSIX-compliant, but that's Linux for you...) The most notable aspect of it is that it's not corrected, by e.g. NTP to synchronize with the rest of the world, as happens to CLOCK_REALTIME. If your RTC has some drift, then the CLOCK_MONOTONIC will not stay in synch with CLOCK_REALTIME.

Interesting, thank you, I'll see if I can account for that.

No, it works correctly for me. dmesg comes from util-linux, please update it. Maybe your system clock and hardware clock are not synchronized?? (And I found dmesg time vs system time time isn't correct over on ServerFault, I hope it helped)

Thank you. Comparing date with hwclock shows that the two are in sync, so that is not the issue. Nice find, though, and could potentially be helpful to other people who have a similar issue in the future.
